# Spring Security and Apache POI Issues

Tags: java, spring, excel, spring-security, apache-poi

I have a Java Spring web application with Spring Security  where the user enters a date, the 
database is queried based on that date and the result is sent back to the user's browser as an excel file via HSSFWorkbook writing to ServletOutputStream.

If the date selected is in the weeks of 12/28/2013-1/4/2014, 1/12/2014-1/18-2014, 1/19/2014-1/25/2014, or 1/26/2014-2/1/2014 the file that is sent to the user for download is converted to the contentType "text/html" even though it is explicitly set to "application/x-ms-excel".

The resulting Excel file is corrupted and contains only strange symbols. This only happens when Spring-Security is included and so far, only for the dates listed.

If anyone has had this problem could you please let me know how you fixed it?

This generates the workbook:

```
public static HSSFWorkbook getExcelRemittance(HashMap<String,List> items)
{
List<ItemView> remit = items.get("remit");
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet;
    sheet = workbook.createSheet("Final Remittance");

    Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell1 = header.createCell(0);
    cell1.setCellValue("DISNEY INVOICE NUM");
    Cell cell2 = header.createCell(1);
    cell2.setCellValue("EBI AMOUNT");
    Cell cell3 = header.createCell(2);
    cell3.setCellValue("PAYING AMOUNT");
    Cell cell4 = header.createCell(3);
    cell4.setCellValue("RESIDUAL AMOUNT");
    Cell cell5 = header.createCell(4);
    cell5.setCellValue("BOOKING #");
    Cell cell6 = header.createCell(5);
    cell6.setCellValue("GUEST NAME");
    Cell cell7 = header.createCell(6);
    cell7.setCellValue("NOTES/Dispute Reason");


    int count = 1;
    double total = 0.0;
    for(ItemView v : remit)
    {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(count++);

        Cell c1 = row.createCell(0);
        c1.setCellValue(v.getDisneyInvoiceNum());
        Cell c2 = row.createCell(1);
        c2.setCellValue(v.getEbiAmount());
        Cell c3 = row.createCell(2);
        c3.setCellValue(v.getEbiAmount());
        Cell c4 = row.createCell(3);
        c4.setCellValue("-");
        Cell c5 = row.createCell(4);
        c5.setCellValue("");
        Cell c6 = row.createCell(5);
        c6.setCellValue("");
        Cell c7 = row.createCell(6);
        c7.setCellValue("");
        total+=v.getEbiAmount();
    }

    Row subTotalRemit = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum()+1);

    int subTotalRow1 = sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;

    Cell t = subTotalRemit.createCell(0);
    t.setCellValue("subtotal");
    Cell tAmt = subTotalRemit.createCell(1);
    tAmt.setCellFormula("SUM(B2:B"+sheet.getLastRowNum()+")");

    List<ItemView> past = items.get("prev");
    Row prevHead = sheet.createRow(count+6);
    Cell remitTitle = prevHead.createCell(0);
    remitTitle.setCellValue("Invoices from previous batches");
    CellStyle cs = workbook.createCellStyle();
    Font f = workbook.createFont();
    f.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    cs.setFont(f);
    remitTitle.setCellStyle(cs);

    Row prevCols = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum()+1);
    Cell ph1= prevCols.createCell(0);
    ph1.setCellValue("Invoice Number");
    Cell ph2= prevCols.createCell(1); 
    ph2.setCellValue("Invoice Amount");
    Cell ph3= prevCols.createCell(2); 
    ph3.setCellValue("Paying Amount");
    Cell ph4= prevCols.createCell(3);
    ph4.setCellValue("Residual Amount");
    Cell ph5= prevCols.createCell(4); 
    ph5.setCellValue("Booking #");
    Cell ph6= prevCols.createCell(5);
    ph6.setCellValue("Guest Name");
    Cell ph7= prevCols.createCell(6); 
    ph7.setCellValue("Notes/Dispute Reason");

    int sum1 = sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
    for(ItemView v : past)
    {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum()+1);
        Cell c1 = row.createCell(0);
        c1.setCellValue(v.getDisneyInvoiceNum());
        Cell c2 = row.createCell(1);
        c2.setCellValue(v.getEbiAmount());
        Cell c3 = row.createCell(2);
        c3.setCellValue(v.getAmountPaid());
        Cell c4 = row.createCell(3);
        c4.setCellValue(v.getDiffEbiApAmt());
        Cell c5 = row.createCell(4);
        c5.setCellValue("");
        Cell c6 = row.createCell(5);
        c6.setCellValue("");
        Cell c7 = row.createCell(6);
        c7.setCellValue(v.getNotes());
    }

    Row subTotalPrev = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum()+1);
    Cell tP = subTotalPrev.createCell(1);
    tP.setCellValue("subtotal");
    Cell tAmtP = subTotalPrev.createCell(2);
    tAmtP.setCellFormula("SUM(C"+sum1+":C"+sheet.getLastRowNum()+")");

    Row gTotal = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum()+1);
    Cell gtP = gTotal.createCell(1);
    gtP.setCellValue("Total");
    Cell gtAmtP = gTotal.createCell(2);
    gtAmtP.setCellFormula("B"+subTotalRow1+"+C"+(sheet.getLastRowNum()));


    return workbook;
}
```

This is the code that sends the file to the user:

```
@RequestMapping(value="generateRemit")
public @ResponseBody String getRemitExcel(
        @RequestParam("date") String date,
        HttpServletResponse response)
{
ServletOutputStream out;
    HSSFWorkbook book = Utils.getExcelRemittance(jdbcBillingDao.getWeeklyRemit(date));
    try {
        response.setContentType("application/x-ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+date+"Remittance Final.xls");
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        log.info("writing to output stream");

        book.write(out);
        out.flush();

        log.info("finished writing to output stream");
//          return book.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        log.info("Error writing to file output stream");
            return e.toString();
    }
return "success";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by returning an AbstractExcelView instead of a redirect:

```
@RequestMapping(value="generateRemit")
protected View remitExcel( @RequestParam("date") String date)
{
    final String finalDate = date;
    return new AbstractExcelView() {
        @Override
        protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, HSSFWorkbook workbook,
                        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+finalDate+"Disney Remittance Final\"");

                HashMap<String,List> items = jdbcBillingDao.getWeeklyRemit(finalDate);

             HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Final Remittance");

             @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<ItemView> remit = items.get("remit");

            Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
            Cell cell1 = header.createCell(0);
            cell1.setCellValue("DISNEY INVOICE NUM");
            Cell cell2 = header.createCell(1);
            cell2.setCellValue("EBI AMOUNT");
            Cell cell3 = header.createCell(2);
            cell3.setCellValue("PAYING AMOUNT");
            Cell cell4 = header.createCell(3);
            cell4.setCellValue("RESIDUAL AMOUNT");
            Cell cell5 = header.createCell(4);
            cell5.setCellValue("BOOKING #");
            Cell cell6 = header.createCell(5);
            cell6.setCellValue("GUEST NAME");
            Cell cell7 = header.createCell(6);
            cell7.setCellValue("NOTES/Dispute Reason");
                          //more spreadsheet generation
        }


      };
```

}